How to create custom elements in HTML on demand?
I am curretly adding some customm elements for an inhouse framework , however I noticed that we are getting all the elements on an index file to use them inside the html.
Do you know a better way to do this ? like a lazy instantiation.
current code :
customElements.define('element-a', ElementA);
customElements.define('element-b', ElementB);
customElements.define('element-c', ElementC);
customElements.define('element-d', ElementD);
customElements.define('element-f', ElementF);
....


I can't tell what question you are asking.  Javascript can certainly create HTML elements on the fly, and I'm guessing that's what your code does.

I want it to be on demand, I found a "way" to make it as annotation for every class but that is not on demand, I would like to know if there is something that helps you check on the document, see if you need a certain element , then define it .. as on demand

I think the custom element has to  be defined before you parse the HTML that contains the corresponding tag. So I don't think there's a way for you to wait until after loading the HTML before you define the elements it needs.

You could possibly use a regexp that looks for <\s*element-a\b in the HTML text. But this would be fragile.

And it would only work if you're loading the HTML dynamically by assigning to .innerHTML, not when loading a .html file.

@Barmar could you explain a bit more about it ?

What more is there to say? You can't load the HTML with custom tags until after you define the custom elements. So there's no way to make the element definition conditional on the HTML you've already loaded.

There's no auto-loader for custom elements.

All Barmar his statements are wrong !!!. Here is a JSFiddle to demo how Web Components work when the JavaScript define comes after the DOM parsing stage. https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/9txjfazc/

You can find custom elements, hide them, load classes async and upgrade elements:


class CustomElement extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback() {
    const template = document.createElement("template")
    template.innerHTML = /* html */ `
      <style>
        :host {
          background-color: yellow;
        }
      </style>

      <slot></slot>
    `
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
    shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
  }
}

const promises = {};

// you can also traverse DOM tree, could be faster
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(async el => {
  if(el.tagName.includes('-')){

    let display;
    [{display}, el.style.display] = [el.style, 'none'];
    const tag = el.tagName.toLowerCase();

    const name = tag.replace(/^\w|-\w/gd, m => m.at(-1).toUpperCase());
    
    // use something like import() to load a custom element class
    let defined = true;
    const factory = await (promises[name] ??= (
      defined = false,
      new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(eval(name)), 200))
    ));
    
    defined || customElements.define(tag, factory),
    
    el.style.display = display;
  }
});
<custom-element>Custom Element</custom-element><br/>
<custom-element>Second Element</custom-element>




okay so what I found useful is the "traverse DOM tree" solution that you mentioned. So basically traverse it , if it find the custom element name then define it.
This helps in a lot of ways. Thanks !

@Kisama329 i've fixed the code to avoid defining an element several times
